# A conjecture by Euler about $8n+3$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problems

Euler's conjecture: For any positive integer $n$, $8n+3$ can be represented as a sum 
$$8n+3=(2k-1)^2+2p,$$
where $k$ is a positive integer, and $p$ is a prime.

I want to know whether there has been progress  on the problem. Could you recommend some references? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

Barry Mazur discussed this problem in his presentation of January 2012, [Why is it plausible?](http://sigmaa.maa.org/pom/PomSigmaa/Mazur1-12Details.pdf) Mazur says there that it is still unsettled.